# Prove convergence in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is convergence coordinate-wise.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

1. Let $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}^3$. We write $x_n = (x_{1,n}, x_{2,n}, x_{3,n}) ( \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$) for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Let $x = (x_1,x_2,x_3)( \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R})$. Show that $x_n \rightarrow x$ (w.r.t. usual metric $d$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$) if and only if $x_{i,n} \rightarrow x_i$ for all $i = 1,2,3$
2. Show that the cube $[0,1]^3$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (w.r.t usual metric $d$). Show the same for the rectangle $[a_1,b_1] \times [a_2,b_2] \times [a_3,b_3]$

i'm having problems with this proof. After I read it a few times I realized it's asking to prove that convergence in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is convergence coordinate-wise. My guess for the backwards direction was simply to call on the converging subsequence theorem (limit of subsequence is limit of entire sequence). I am stumped for the rigorous forwards direction proof. Please don't 'jump' in the proofs!

Using 1 any help on 2 would be appreciated!

Comment: Hint: Show that $|x_1-x_{i,n}| \leq |((x_1,x_2,x_3)-(x_{1,n},x_{2,n},x_{3,n})|$  (use the triangle inequality a few times) and then use the epsilon delta definition of convergence.

Comment: Please: Write $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R \times \mathbb R$, not $\mathbb R$ x $\mathbb R$ x $\mathbb R$. $\qquad$

Comment: Could you show me how the triangle inequality would work through the proof?

Comment: you prove it I'm sick